# CNF with Nested Quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, conjunctive-normal-form

I have the following statement:
$$\ 
\forall Z \forall X ((A(Z) \land S(Z,X)\land (\exists Q (P(Q) \land E(Z,Q)))) \implies E(X,Z)) 
$$
Which (I hope) can be read as "For all X and Z, if A(Z) and S(Z,X) and there exists a Q with P(Q) and E(Z,Q)) then E(X,Z))

In the process of reducing to CNF (this is part of a resolution problem), I have reached this:
$$\
\forall Z \forall X (¬A(Z) \lor ¬S(Z,X)\lor (\forall Q (¬P(Q) \lor ¬E(Z,Q)) \lor E(X,Z)) 
$$
I'm aware of skolemising where Exists is used instead of ForAll, but not sure how to deal with the nested ForAll. My intuition says to move the ForAll Q to the beginning of the sentence, as surely this would have the same meaning, but I'm not sure how to justify this.

Would this be valid to do?

Thanks!

Comment: To be precise, it must be read as : ""For all Z and X, ..."

Comment: The first step in the transform must be : $∀Z∀X \ [A(Z) ∧ S(Z,X) ∧ (∀Q(¬P(Q) ∨ ¬E(Z,Q) ∨ E(X,Z))]$.

Comment: We have no negation sign in front to transform $A(Z) ∧ S(Z,X) ∧ \ldots$ into $¬A(Z) ∨ ¬S(Z,X) ∨ \ldots$.

Comment: Sorry I had missed out a bracket. The negation comes from CNF reduction of implication. so $$\ A \implies B $$ becomes $$\ ¬A \lor B $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Prenex Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) specify if and how you can pull out quantifiers.

Specific to your sentence, you have that where $\varphi$ is any formula and  $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$$  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi)$$

So yes, you can indeed pull out the quantifier as is, and obtain:

$$\
\forall Z \forall X \forall Q (¬A(Z) \lor ¬S(Z,X)\lor ¬P(Q) \lor ¬E(Z,Q) \lor E(X,Z)) 
$$

Now, why does this prenex law hold? I'll give a very informal 'proof':

A universal can be seen as kind of conjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of a universal like this:

$$\forall x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...$$

(I use $\approx$ here, since this is really not any kind of properly defined equivalence, and why this isn't a genuine proof either ... but it'll get the basic idea across)

As such, we thus have:

$$ \psi \lor \forall x \varphi(x) \approx$$

$$\psi \lor (\varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$(\psi \lor \varphi(a) ) \land (\psi \lor \varphi(b)) \land (\psi \lor \varphi(c) ) \land ...  \approx$$

$$\forall x (\psi \lor \varphi(x)  ) $$